# Error with factorial in python using classes

Tags: python

I am trying to write a class to solve factorials using recursion.

Here is my code:

```
class Factorial:

def __init__(self,n):
self.n = n

def factorial(self):
    if self.n == 0:
        return 1 
    else:
        return self.n * self.factorial(self.n - 1)
```

I call it by:

```
 fact = Factorial(4) 
 fact.factorial()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "factorial.py", line 13, in <module>
    fact.factorial()
  File "factorial.py", line 10, in factorial
    return self.n * self.factorial(self.n - 1)
  TypeError: factorial() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thanks

Comment: You've only declared your `factorial` function to take a `self` argument.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're doing this with a class rather than just a normal function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your instance variable with a parameter passed to your method.

`factorial` should look like:

```
def factorial(self):
    if self.n == 0:
        return 1 
    else:
        temp_n = self.n
        self.n -= 1
        return temp_n * self.factorial() # alternatively, (self.n + 1)*self.factorial()
```

You want to 1) decrement the `n` variable, then 2) multiply by the factorial of `n-1`.

May I ask why you're doing it this way?

Comment: No special reason other than just learning and exploration. I'd like to build my own statistics engine for person use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a factorial that actually works for arguments that aren't rather small, you should do something like

```
def factorial(self):
    ans = 1
    loop = self.n
    while loop>0:
        ans *= loop
        loop -= 1
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated ur code and it worked plz chk this one

```
class Factorial:

    def fact(self,n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1 
        else:
            return n * self.fact(n - 1)

f = Factorial()
print(f.fact(4))
```

Comment: There is no reason to make factorial a stateful class. Horrible practice.

Answer (score -1):

use this it working fine

class Factorial():
def fact(self,n):
if n==1:
return 1
else:
return n * self.fact(n - 1)
ob=Factorial()
res=ob.fact(5)
print(res)

Comment: Please format the code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
class A:
    def Show(self):
        self.num=int(input("Enter the number:"))
        self.f=1
        for self.x in range(1,self.num+1):
            self.f=self.f*self.x
        print("Fact=",self.f)
a1=A()
a1.Show()
```

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?

Comment: (Also, this solution is _awful_. Why is there a class? Why is it given a useless name like `A`? Why is its only method given a generic name like `Show`? Why is that method capitalized? What's the point of `self.f`? Why is the iteration value called `self.x` instead of just `x`? Why does the method _print_ its output instead of returning it? That's just one of the many reasons that AI-generated answers are banned.)